# How to assign a shortcut on a button in SwiftUI on MacOS for iOS Project(Catalyst enabled)?

Tags: swiftui, mac-catalyst

I have a button on my view and I want to handle key events to perform something. How to do it? 
`#if os(macOS)` is false cause the project is mobile with enabled MacOS via Catalyst.

```swift
#if os(macOS)
extension Command {
    static let voiceSelectedText = Command(Selector("voiceSelectedText:"))
}
#endif

var body: some View {
    let button = Button(action: {
    }) {
        Text("Voice (Space)")
    }

    #if os(macOS)
        return button.onCommand(.voiceSelectedText) {

        }
    #else
        return button
    #endif

}
```

## Update

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
// runs on macOS
#endif
```

```swift
#if os(iOS)
// works always
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.onCommand()` modifier.

[WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/240/) around **22:30**

Comment: I want to clarify that this iOS project with included macOS support through Catalyst and `#if os(macOS)` is false.