# How to manually show contextMenu in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to show contextMenu by clicking on the left mouse button?
How to manually show view in SwiftUI?

```swift
Image(systemName: "book")
.contextMenu {
   Text("something1")
   Text("something2")
   Text("something3")
}
```

Comment: You mention mouse button, which makes me think this is about macOS, but you are also using Image(systemName:) which is not available in macOS. Which system are you building for?

Comment: I created iOS project and enabled Catalyst. Image:systemName works but not all images are available.

Comment: When you look at image declaration in SwiftUI you will find that this initialiser in not available: extension Image {

    @available(OSX, unavailable)
    public init(systemName: String)
}

Comment: I already wrote that the compile considers the project as iOS here https://stackoverflow.com/q/57923102/4067700

Comment: I added new question about emulating iOS apps on macOS https://stackoverflow.com/q/58104898/4067700

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `MenuButton` with a `menuButtonStyle` to create a button which, when clicked, shows a menu.  Seems to be Mac only currently.

```
MenuButton("Menu") {
    Button(action: {
      print("Clicked an item")
    }) {
        Text("Menu Item Text")                
    }
}.menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle())
```

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the size of the hit area? I am able to set a View as label, however it remains the same size.

Answer (score 2):

The currently accepted answer uses [MenuButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menubutton), which is now deprecated. Below is how to use the new [Menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu) option.

This is possible now via [Menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu) (iOS 14+, MacOS 11+)
Menus are covered in this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10052/) at ~11:15.

Playground Example:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            // Other views
            Text("Example View 1")

            // Button, that when tapped shows 3 options
            Menu {
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Label("Add", systemImage: "plus.circle")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "minus.circle")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil.circle")
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

If you wish to support MacOS 10.15 you could do something like:

```
if #available(iOS 14, macOS 11, *) {
    Menu {
        Button(action: {
            
        }) {
            Label("Add", systemImage: "plus.circle")
        }
        Button(action: {
            
        }) {
            Label("Delete", systemImage: "minus.circle")
        }
        Button(action: {
            
        }) {
            Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil.circle")
        }
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
    }
} else if #available(macOS 10.15, *) {
    MenuButton(
        label: Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: NSImage.actionTemplateName)!),
        content: {
            Button(action: {}) {
                HStack {
                    Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: NSImage.addTemplateName)!)
                    Text("Add")
                }
            }
            Button(action: {}) {
                HStack {
                    Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: NSImage.removeTemplateName)!)
                    Text("Delete")
                }
            }
            Button(action: {}) {
                HStack {
                    Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: NSImage.refreshTemplateName)!)
                    Text("Edit")
                }
            }
        })
        .menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle())
} else {
    // Custom code here would be needed to support iOS 13 and MacOS 10.14
}
```

Comment: What about backwards compatibility and macOS 10.15? Menu API is not available there, can we still use MenuButton? I'm building an app and that troubles me.

Comment: @Gabb - I have added an example for macOS 10.15 compatibility.