# What mouse gesture to delete an item from a List on macOS in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I don't understand how to delete or move a item on macOS. What action should I need to do with the mouse to trigger `onDelete` or `onMove` events?

```swift
 @State var wishList = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item3"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(wishList, id:\.self) { item in
                Button(action: {
                }) {
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
            .onDelete { offsets in
            }
            .onMove { source, target in
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue? both `onMove` and `onDelete` are working correctly.

Comment: To remove an item from the list on iPhone I use the swipe left gesture on macOS. I try to make same gesture on macOS by mouse but nothing happens.

Comment: Swipe with Two fingers. Like horizontal scrolling

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Move**:
  Click and drag rows.
- **Delete**:
  Swipe with (two fingers on trackpad or one finger on magic mouse), like the way you scroll horizontally.

Note that **you should NOT** click and drag the row like the way you swipe in iOS simulator. Just a simple mac horizontal scroll is enough.

Comment: My question was about mouse gestures. 
Move: left click and drag.
Delete: Swipe to the left with one finger .

Answer (score 1):

These gestures won't work if you have an ordinary two-button mouse. You will need to make affordances in your UI for people with simpler mice.